# Some riscv32 disassembler results are 16bits not 32bits. How to fix it?

Tags: riscv

I want to get dump file of riscv32 gnu-toolchain to see its instructions. First, use gnu-toolchain to compile c code by command below:

$riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc hello.c -o hello.out

Then, disassemble elf by the command:

$riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump -d hello.out > hello.dump

However, as I open dump file, some of the instructions are 16bits not 32bits e.g. 8e09 for sub instruction etc. Whats wrong with my commands since I am aimed to generate 32bit instructions in jump file?

Comment: please provide a minimal example, the disassembler is going to just disassemble what it sees.  you might be looking at disassembly of data which is not instructions.  also variable length disassembly is difficult at best, just try to use binutils on x86 for example, often it is a complete fail.

Comment: you are linking in other code with your command line and that code might be compressed, need to make sure all of your project is rv32i and not rv32ic, not just the hello.c part.

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been fixed finally by myself and note below is a reference for people in need.

The problem is caused by the command I use to compile is default-installed GNU RV32gc compilation, where extension 'c' means compact instruction set so some instructions generated may belong to it.

To make disassembler results totally be 32bits, you just need to add flags to tell RV32gc not using c's instruction subset to compile in advance. That is to say, let's modify original command to limit to rv32i as shown below and disassembler result would just be 32bits.

$riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 hello.c -o hello.out